# Can we Html.Listbox for draggable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.listboxfor

Basically, I'm using Html.Listboxfor with 'MultiSelectList' options. The trouble I have is, I want the listbox to expand as per the length of the text within that listbox. I'm using following style, any inputs to make this happen??

```css
display: inline;
  width:100%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  /*float: left;
  clear: left;*/
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #555555;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #ffffff;
```

Alternatively, if I can provide drag option where users can drag the list box to see the full text width, that would be beneficial too.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please read my headline as "Can we make Html.Listboxfor as dragable?". Sorry for the typo!

Comment: And here is the listbox snippet: `code` "@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.multiiterations, new MultiSelectList(Enumerable.Empty<MultiSelectList>()), new { @id = "iterationList", @class = "form-control" })". form-control has the css code given in my question. thanks.